# How to update data attribute on Ajax complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, octobercms

I'm using October CMS and in the framework I can make an AJAX call using the following HTML element:

```
<a href="#" class="sbutton" data-request="onSavedeal" 
     data-request-data="deal_ID:'14779255',type:'local',active:'0'">
    <i class="material-icons pink-text listfavorite">favorite</i>                      
</a>
```

Whenever this link is clicked on a favorite button fires off an update to a controller "onSavedeal". Updating the database works fine on the first click. However, after updating, the value for the "data-request-data" attribute isn't updated so the button does not work for subsequent clicks.

I need to make the link change so that "active:'0'" becomes "active:'1'". The resulting full element would be

```
<a href="#" class="sbutton" data-request="onSavedeal" 
     data-request-data="deal_ID:'14779255',type:'local',active:'1'">
    <i class="material-icons pink-text listfavorite">favorite</i>                      
</a>
```

In the framework I can add another attribute called "data-request-success" which executes a javascript function (or code) up successful completion of the AJAX call. How can I make a function called "updateactive()" which would toggle the active value between 0 and 1. The final element should look like:

```
<a href="#" class="sbutton" data-request="onSavedeal" 
     data-request-data="deal_ID:'14779255',type:'local',active:'0'"
     data-reuqest-success="updateactive();">
    <i class="material-icons pink-text listfavorite">favorite</i>                      
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can safely identify this `a` element by attribute `data-request` having value `onSavedeal`, you would write the `updateactive` function as follows:

```
function updateactive() {
    var newAttrValue = "deal_ID:'14779255',type:'local',active:'1'";
    $('[data-request="onSavedeal"]').attr('data-request-data', newAttrValue);
 }
```

Don't forget to correct `data-reuqest-success` to `data-request-success`.

**UPDATE**
If you have many `a` elements on the page, you can reuse same function like below. Check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/a9we13pu/) .

```
function updateactive() {
    var clickedA = event.currentTarget,
        newAttrValue = $(clickedA).attr('data-request-data').replace("active:'0'", "active:'1'");

    $(clickedA).attr('data-request-data', newAttrValue);
}
```

Comment: The problem in this use case has hundreds of deals, so making a separate javascript function for each one isn't feasible. Further, this would leave the newAttrValue as static since the page isn't being reloaded after the Ajax call.

Comment: Can you address this problem by getting the current value of `data-request-data` attribute of clicked `a` and simply replacing `active:'0'` with `active:'1'`?

Comment: will `event` be defined?

Comment: Yes, it will. You can check my fiddle to make sure. Explore the attribute in question before and after click.

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't see how your answer is adding to the solution. Did you just make my answer shorter a little?

Answer (score 0):

Make change to your anchor tag this way

```
<a href="#" class="sbutton" data-request="onSavedeal" 
 data-request-data="deal_ID:'14779255',type:'local',active:'0'"
 data-reuqest-success="updateactive(this);">
<i class="material-icons pink-text listfavorite">favorite</i>
```

Note the change `updateactive(this);`

Then in your jquery you can have the function definition this way.

```
 function updateactive(element) {        
    $(element).attr('data-request-data', $(element).attr('data-request-data').replace("active:'0'", "active:'1'"));
}
```